# discord.py - Updating Specific Messages

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted my bot to edit an message every 5 minutes.

For example

```
msg = discord.utils.get(message, "edited")
cliend.edit_message(message, msg)
```

Comment: What do you know about the message you want to edit?  Are you sending the message, or are you trying to find a message that already exists?

Comment: Editing the own bots message by Id (if possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```py
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

messages=[]
async def edit_msg():
    num=0
    while True:
        if messages:
            for i in messages:
                await bot.edit_message(i,new_content=f'This is message {num}')
                num+=1
        await asyncio.sleep(300)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await edit_msg()
    print(f"{bot.user.name} is ready to run!")


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def edit_me(con,*,message):
    msg=await bot.say(message)
    messages.append(msg)


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def edit_emb(msg):
    emb=discord.Embed(title='Title Embed')
    emb.add_field(name='name of the embed',value='value for field')
    reply=await bot.say(embed=emb)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

    new_embed=discord.Embed(title='New embed')
    new_embed.add_field(name='new emb',value='the new value')
    await bot.edit_message(reply,embed=new_embed)
```

Comment: discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Cannot edit a message authored by another user

Comment: Yeah, sorry my mistake. Edited the answer, try it again now.

Comment: change the editor to this `-->`  `bot.edit_message(i,embed=emb)` for embeds.
Also I added another example in the answer